# Mysql explain query scan more rows then what actual returns

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql **5.6.22-log**

I am executing query on table aggr, with all the condition in where clause.

Following are the data

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE aggr (
 a_date DATE,
 product_id INT(11),
 data_point VARCHAR(16),
 los INT(11),
 hour_0 DOUBLE(4,2),
 UNIQUE KEY `unique_row` (a_date,product_id,data_point,los),
 INDEX product_id(product_id)
);
```

**Insert queries**

```
INSERT INTO aggr(a_date,product_id,data_point,los,hour_0) 
VALUES
('2018-07-29',1,'arrivals',1,10),('2018-07-29',1,'departure',1,9),
('2018-07-29',1,'solds',1,12),('2018-07-29',1,'revenue',1,45.20),
('2018-07-30',1,'arrivals',2,10),('2018-07-30',1,'departure',2,9),
('2018-07-30',1,'solds',2,12),('2018-07-30',1,'revenue',2,45.20),

('2018-07-29',2,'arrivals',1,10),('2018-07-29',2,'departure',1,9),
('2018-07-29',2,'solds',1,12),('2018-07-29',2,'revenue',1,45.20),
('2018-07-30',2,'arrivals',2,10),('2018-07-30',2,'departure',2,9),
('2018-07-30',2,'solds',2,12),('2018-07-30',2,'revenue',2,45.20);
```

**Query**

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM aggr
WHERE a_date BETWEEN '2018-07-29' AND '2018-07-29' 
AND product_id = 1 
AND data_point IN('arrivals','departure' ,'solds','revenue') 
AND los = 1 ;
```

**Question**

1. Above query scan 8 rows (while as per the where condition it should scan only 4 rows )

[image]

**Expected Result :**

It should scan only 4 rows instead of 8 rows.

Can some one explain why mysql scan 8 rows instead of 4 rows?

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is a deadlock. But you're asking why it scans 8 and returns 4. Why do you think it should scan as many rows as it returns? It says `type = ALL`. That means it looks at all the rows. It doesn't use an index because it's slower to use an index for such a small table. You have 8 rows in the table so it looks at all of them, determines it needs 4 due to `WHERE` and returns those 4.

Comment: @N.B. Table has total 16 rows. I have specify all condition in where clause which is used in unique key.  But sill it scan 8 rows,  not 4 or 16.

Comment: Hi All, mentioning Deadlock in question create lot of confusion, I have remove that part.

Comment: My comment still stands. There is no rule that says that MySQL will scan X rows and return X rows.

Comment: @N.B. I am not saying that your are wrong, but What I am asking is that , because of above query If I ran delete query with same criteria in two different session then delete query in transaction lock on same data. you can check information_Schema.INNODB_LOCKS table to verify the lock_data.

Comment: Now we're running in circles. First you ask why MySQL scans more rows than it returns. Then you mention deadlock. Then it turns out your **real problem** is a deadlock, again. A deadlock is not something BAD. It's MySQL's way of dealing with concurrency. If you have 2 delete queries trying to do the same thing at the same time, one must fail so other one succeeds. Now.. is there any real problem here or is it just that you think a deadlock is bad and you don't "want" it?

Comment: @N.B. Yes because of this on my production environment when multiple thread try to delete  some record from single table with above same criteria Mysql generate deadlock and one of the transaction gets fail.

Comment: That's normal behavior. What would you want to happen? What's the "fix" for you?

Comment: @N.B. so what I understand is, if two different query scan different row then dead lock want generate. so with above query if I execute two different query with **product_id 1 and 2** then it should lock different data, if I achieve this then probably deadlock wont generate. with this above query does not apply all where condition to search the data.

Comment: No... not if they **scan**, if they **write**. `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are **writes**. If two queries try to write to the **same row**, one MUST fail. If a deadlock happens, that is just a warning, it's not an error. If you deal with different data, you won't get deadlocks.

Comment: @N.B. If one query insert with product_id 2 and second query delete with product_id with all other criteria same then does Mysql lock both transactions ?

Comment: You can't delete if it doesn't exist.. if it's an update and delete, then a deadlock would occur.

Comment: @N.B. data is exists for product_id 1 and 2, so first thread (for product_id=1) execute delete and then insert, second thread (product_id=2) came and try to delete, then at this point Mysql goes into wait mode, and I checked that **lock_data** uses same hex for both transaction. (expected it should be different because product id for both transaction is different).

Answer (score 1):

`EXPLAIN` statement is used to obtain information about how the query is executed. The `rows` number is an **approximation only**, used by the query optimizer to make decisions when it builds an execution plan. It is a tool for getting diagnostic information by database administration or developer.

What the result of `EXPLAIN` is actually showing you is that you have no usable index for your query (`key` is `(NULL)`). This is quite bad and can cause significant slowdowns for this query. By looking at your table definition, I would say that you need a separate index for `data_point`, or at least try to make make it the last column for your primary key.

However, none of this is enough to explain the deadlock. I'm not even sure why you are showing us `EXPLAIN` here - it has nothing to do with it. To be able to diagnose a deadlock, you need to privide more information. Start with the type of your table (`MyISAM`, `InnoDB` etc.) and `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`. Then, for each process, see what locks it's holding for each table.